# Как из побочного потока запустить метод в основном потоке?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Столкнулся с небольшой проблемой, сделал дополнительный поток для обработки информации, и нужно, используя её, запускать метод в основном потоке из побочного (в нем есть функции, которые работают только в основном потоке), но как это сделать не понимаю. Видел способ с Handler, но делаю в unity и пишет, что такого пространства имен нет. Что можно сделать?

Comment: Я в юнити не шарю,  но слова для поиска: диспетчер потока,  контекст синхронизации

Comment: @tym32167, не, в юнити скорее свои механизмы

Comment: к сожалению, я не знаю об этих механизмах)

Comment: Укажите используемую технологию. Это действительно Unity? Добавьте метку.

Comment: забыл добавить её